# ActiveAdmin status_tag not rendering inside table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm working on my first activeadmin project and I'm trying to create a panel on the dashboard that displays a status for each of my estimates.

The status_tag is displaying outside the table though. If i change it to just some text value rather than the status_tag it works just fine.

Why is the status_tag way up top and how can I fix it?

Example screenshot
http://snag.gy/iHYz2.jpg

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do

     columns do
       column do
         panel "Recent Estimates" do

           table_for Estimate.last(5) do 
             column :description
             column :name
             column :status, status_tag('In Progress')
           end
         end
       end

     end
  end # content
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems that instead of this:

```
column :status, status_tag('In Progress')
```

I needed to do:

```
column(:status) {|estimate| status_tag(estimate.status)}
```